# Cloud Computing

Tags: cloud, cloud-hosting

I hear the term Cloud-Computing a lot these days so i decided to google around to find out exactly what it is and whether it can benefit me.

I am struggling to find out exactly what is the difference in cloud-computing and your standard hosting of a server using a host somewhere else which is a service has existed for many years.

Is it just a fancy name for hosting?

Comment: We sure get this question a lot. No matter how many times you ask it, it's still not on topic, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloud computing is where you are not in control of or have no way of really knowing what machines are doing your computations.  Think of a service such as Amazon's EC2 or Microsoft's Azure, where you simply rent CPU cycles/space and you have no idea how it is load balanced, allocated, whether it is running on one machine or ten.  This is cloud computing.

To the lay person, though, Cloud Computing is often understood as hosted somewhere on the Internet, but this is a simplification of the actual meaning of the term.

Comment: I can rent server space or dedicated servers from my hosting provider. For scaling i can rent more servers if i need to. The only difference i see is that have to know when i need more servers whereas in cloud maybe that is managed for you.

Comment: You usually have to write your programs in a way that is tailored to the cloud computing platform ziggy, which you don't have to do for normal rented remote servers.  Azure, EC2, and Google Apps all impose techniques for dealing with distribution of data and load that you have to be aware of.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud computing refers to scalable hosting, where you can add and remove servers in real time.

Comment: Yes but scalable hosting has always existed hasnt it?

Comment: @ziggy - No, not always. For example, there was no scalable hosting in the 17th century.